# Проблема с !empty

Tags: php

У меня есть данный код:

```
$text = $attr['something'];
if (!empty($text)){
  echo ''; // ничего не выводит
} else {
  echo '<li>'.$attr['something'].'</li>';
}
$output = $text;
```

Код работает, если поле с атрибутом ['something'] пустое, то он ничего не выводит
Но если я ввожу туда просто текст, он выведет его, но уже без `li` элемента.
В чем может быть проблема?
Другими словами мне нужно чтобы если значение $attr['something'] было пустое, то не выводить ничего, а если там хоть что-то написано, то вывести то что написано внутри `li` элемента
С php познакомился не так давно, буду благодарен за любую помощь

p.s я понял почему $output выводится без `li` элемента, потому что он просто выводит то что написано в $attr['something'], но я по прежнему не понимаю как вывести html код если значение не пустует

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ну во первых:**

> ...если значение $attr['something'] было пустое, то не выводить ничего...

```
if (!empty($text)){
  echo ''; // ничего не выводит
}
```

Как-то на реалии не похоже, надо убрать `!`.

**Во вторых:**

Как вы определили что у вас `<li>` не выводится? в браузере? посмотрите исходный код страницы. Если вам нужно прям на экране увидеть `<li>` то http://php.net/manual/ru/function.htmlspecialchars.php

**В третьих:**

Так что вы хотите в `$output` - видеть результат для вывода? тогда так:

```
$text = $attr['something'];
if (empty($text)){
   $output = ''; // ничего не выводит
} else {
  $output = '<li>'.$attr['something'].'</li>';
}
echo $output;
```